# rpmbuild is not reading macros from rpmrc file

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, suse, sles

I am trying to build a code on SLES-15 and in Makefile it executes rpmbuild command as below.

`rpmbuild -ba --rcfile $(BUILDROOT)/scripts/rpmrc --rmsource --target $(RPM_TARGET_ARCH) $(DEBUG_OPTION) $(RPMDIR)/SPECS/$(SPECFILE)`

rpmrc file has below contents:

> macrofiles: /usr/lib/rpm/macros:/usr/lib/rpm/%{_target}/macros:/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/macros:/etc/rpm/macros.specspo:/etc/rpm/macros.cdb:/etc/rpm/macros.prelink:/etc/rpm/macros.solve:/etc/rpm/macros.up2date:/etc/rpm/macros:/etc/rpm/%{_target}/macros:~/.rpmmacros:/home/build/builds/Sourcecode/rpm/rpmmacros

the file /home/build/builds/Sourcecode/rpm/rpmmacros has definition

> %_topdir /home/build/builds/code/build/Linux-i686-SLES11/Release/tools 
> #Override default __os_install_post macro 
> #Do not strip comment section of binaries as this 
> #causes aveserver to fail its integrity check
>
> #XXX: Apparently, only RedHat strips in post install by default 
> #so explicitly strip everything

> %__os_install_post      
> /usr/lib/rpm/brp-compress 
> /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip 
> /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip-shared 
> /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip-static-archive 
> %{nil}

> #Enable debuginfo packages for SuSE build
> #XXX: This requires a working eu-strip from the elfutils package
> #which normally does not come with SLES
> %install %{debug_package}
> %%install
> %{nil}

But when rpmbuild command is executed It actually picks different value of ‘_topdir’ (which it reads from /usr/lib/rpm/macros) and failed with error XXX not found.

The _topdir problem was solved by adding extra macro definition to rpmbuild command (as below)

`rpmbuild -ba **--define='_topdir $(RPMDIR)'** --rcfile $(BUILDROOT)/scripts/rpmrc --rmsource --target $(RPM_TARGET_ARCH) $(DEBUG_OPTION) $(RPMDIR)/SPECS/$(SPECFILE)`

but later on fails with different directory not found error, which I believe is due as it not reading/picking macros from rpmrc file. Any Solution for this? Why its not reading macros from user provided macro/rpmrc files.

***This code  builds on SLES-11 but failes on SLES-15*** 
RPM version on SLES-15             Version: 4.14.3   Release: 40.1 
RPM version on SLES-11             Version: 4.4.2.3  Release: 37.16.37

**Note:** rpmbuild is picking macro definition from /*usr/lib/rpm/suse/macros* and */usr/lib/rpm/macros*. Also, */usr/lib/rpm/suse/macros* overrides the definition from */usr/lib/rpm/macros*. For eg if '**%_XXX**' is defined in both files */usr/lib/rpm/macros* and */usr/lib/rpm/suse/macros*, then rpmbuild picks value of **%_XXX** from */usr/lib/rpm/suse/macros*.

Answer (score 0):

RPM stops supporting macrofiles reading from rcfile from v4.6 onwards.
The solution is to copy rpmmacros files to ~/.rpmmacros.
Other solution was to provide macros file list separated with ":" with --macros= from rpmbuild.